# how can i remove the first forward slash?

Tags: php, breadcrumbs

as you can see i show some breadcrumbs on my page. but i want to remove the first forward slash, how can i do that?

now it looks like this:
/ u are here: /home /page1 /page2

but it has to be like this:
u are here: /home /page1 /page2

i already tried a lot but nothing seems to work.

This is my code:

```
                    <?php
                    $crumbs = explode("/", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);

                    foreach ($crumbs as $crumb) {
                        echo ucfirst(str_replace(foldernaam,'u are here: ', $crumb  . " /"));
                    }
                    ?>
```

Comment: u can use `ltrim();` to remove / before using explode

Comment: You need quotes or do something with `(foldernaam,`

Comment: [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) may be worth looking into

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code:

```
$str = '/u are here /home /page1 /page2';
$str = ltrim($str, '/');
echo $str;
```

It will return you `u are here /home /page1 /page2`

You can also use this code:

```
$str = '/u are here /home /page1 /page2';
$strs = substr($str, 0);
```

But it will remove first character while the code given above will remove the first forward slash that is suitable solution of your query.

Comment: yeah. that should do it.

Comment: sorry. I'm not the OP.

Comment: it works, thank you for this simple but effective solution